# ffmpeg: remove lame replaygain tag from mp3

Tags: ffmpeg, lame, replaygain

lame is writing a replaygain tag if the option `--noreplaygain` is not set:

```
ffmpeg -i testgain_0.mp3
Input #0, mp3, from 'testgain_0.mp3':
Duration: 00:01:00.42, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 192 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : LAME3.99r
Side data:
  replaygain: track gain - -12.500000, track peak - unknown, album gain - unknown, album peak - unknown,
```

Can I use ffmpeg to remove the "Side data"? In my trys with `map metadata` I cannot access this "Side data" to remove it: `-map 0:0 -map_metadata -1`

Comment: There's a [filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sidedata_002c-asidedata) to remove side data  but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to get removed if you roundtrip it via MP4.

```
ffmpeg -i testgain_0.mp3 -c copy testgain_0.mp4

ffmpeg -i testgain_0.mp4 -c copy nogain_0.mp3
```

Or use a pipe for a single-step method:

```
ffmpeg -i testgain_0.mp3 -c copy -f avi - | ffmpeg -i - -c copy nogain_0.mp3
```

Comment: Hi, Mulvya, thanks, but both of the methods produce a frame count mismatch between the Xing header and the audiostream...

Comment: How are you checking that?

Comment: With [link](http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/) Maybe, it could be fixed in an additional step..

Comment: Only happens here if the original MP3 was trimmed from another MP3. You can suppress the msg with `-write_xing 0`

Comment: Oh, thanks for the hint with `-write_xing 0`. Can you explain, what means the single `-`  in `ffmpeg -i - -c copy`?